# Angular 5 webpack compilation error

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular5

After upgrading to Angular 5 and Cli 1.5, on `ng serve` I am getting an error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@stomp/ng2-stompjs/index.ts
    Module build failed: Error: ...\project\node_modules\@stomp\ng2-stompjs\index.ts is not part of the compilation output. Please check the other error messages for details.
        at AngularCompilerPlugin.getCompiledFile (...\project\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js:629:23)
        at plugin.done.then (...\project\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\loader.js:467:39)
        at <anonymous>
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
     @ ./src/app/app.module.ts 27:0-63
     @ ./src/main.ts
     @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:0 ./src/main.ts
```

I have tried to add `include` to my `tsconfig.app.json` so it looks like this:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "module": "es2015",
    "baseUrl": "",
    "types": []
  },
  "include": [
    "../node_modules/@stomp/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

I tried re-run `ng serve` I got another error:

```
    ERROR in ./src/main.ts
Module build failed: Error: ...project\chatAngular4\src\main.ts is not part of the compilation output. Please check the other error messages for details.
    at AngularCompilerPlugin.getCompiledFile (...project\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js:629:23)
    at plugin.done.then (...project\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\loader.js:467:39)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
 @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:0 ./src/main.ts
ERROR in ./src/polyfills.ts
Module build failed: Error: C:\Users\MEP2\Desktop\chatAngular4\src\polyfills.ts is not part of the compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.
    at AngularCompilerPlugin.getCompiledFile (...project\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js:624:23)
    at plugin.done.then (...project\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\loader.js:467:39)
    at <anonymous>
 @ multi ./src/polyfills.ts
```

This looks like it needs some kind of generic workaround. Any ideas?

---

**Update**

After updating all packages to latest version, problem disapeared

Comment: stomp js is to be blamed for i guess

Comment: `'suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,` add this to your tsconfig file

Comment: The Angular 5 changes are not yet released to NPM. Also it is not fully fixed yet. I will try to work on it today.

Comment: What OS and terminal program do use use? In fact, I've got the same error if I run `ng serve` from Windows  `cmd.exe`. However,if I use bash on the same environment, there is no such a problem.

Comment: After latest package updates, problem disapeared

Answer (score 4):

Try `ng serve --preserve-symlinks`.

It helps in most cases for current version of Angular.

Or else simply don't run `ng serve` from symbolically linked folder. Run it from the real one.

Looking forward when they fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error as you in regards to main.ts and polyfills.ts not being included in the configuration.

I added those files to the "include" section of the tsconfig.app.json file and it started working for me.

Oddly enough, after I added this to my first project, I created another project and didn't have to take that extra step.

Here is my tsconfig.app.json:

```
   {
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "module": "es2015",
    "types": []
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "main.ts",
    "polyfills.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Could you please share your tsconfig.app.json?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into the README.md of ng2-stompjs's Github Repo:

https://github.com/stomp-js/ng2-stompjs/tree/angular5#agular-5--ionic

> In src/tsconfig.app.json place the following in compilerOptions:
>
> ```
> "paths": {
>     "@stomp/ng2-stompjs": ["../node_modules/@stomp/ng2-stompjs"]
> }
> ```

Comment: As I see, it doesn't any good to ERROR in ./src/main.ts and ./src/polyfills.ts